# How trustworthy are polls by pinpoll

Tags: sec

I was recently looking at security issues from online-polls and the problem with online-elections and how they can sometimes very easily be tampered with.

Now it sprung to my eye that a lot of websites that I visit and even local newspapers in my area use "pinpoll" for online-polls.

So I wanted to know how trustworthy and secure these polls are?

Comment: Please keep StackOverflow for specific programming-related questions.
Your question is better suited for something like quora.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tobias here, Founder and CEO of [Pinpoll](https://www.pinpoll.com).

I agree with @GreyFairer, let's not discuss this on SO (unless you want to know why fingerprinting libraries shouldn't be used to identify individual clients or how Pinpoll is applying ws to broadcast live updates across the globe).

Just send me an e-mail to [privacy@pinpoll.com](http://mailto:privacy@pinpoll.com) and I'm happy to explain to you in more detail what we do (and cannot do) to protect polls agains bots and fake votes.

And let me make one thing clear: **we're one of the most trustworthy providers** in Europe, especially when it comes to complying with the EU's strict data protection laws.

One example: You won't find a single request to a server other than our own (located in the EU) in our interactive elements.

And one last thing: What might be annoying to you (which is fully accepted), is interesting and entertaining to others. So let's agree to disagree when it comes to online polls in news portals ;)